# Since an Associated Token Account for a wallet can be created by anybody, how can we enforce that Token-2022 immutable ownership is performed on ATAs?

Tags: spl-token, associated-token-account, token-2022, immutable-owner

Here we see that anybody can create an ATA for anybody else's wallet for any token:

- https://spl.solana.com/associated-token-account#creating-an-associated-token-account

But the process of enforcing Token-2022 Program's immutable ownership extension is applied to ATA at the time of ATA creation:

- https://spl.solana.com/token-2022/extensions#immutable-owner

Above we see that `createInitializeImmutableOwnerInstruction` is performed in a transaction that creates the ATA right before `createInitializeAccountInstruction` in the transaction, all of which happens well after the creation of a mint that doesn't speak to enforcing immutable ownership in any way.

How can we ensure that a 3rd party that creates these ATAs for your token for somebody's wallet is indeed creating those ATAs with immutable ownership?

I do see this seemingly ambiguous statement: `The Associated Token Account program always uses this extension when creating accounts.` But I am confused about what this means because if it literally does this by default without any intervention by anyone in any way, why are there instructions and a code example on how to do it? Everything about the context in this documentation gives the impression it is an opt-in extension.

If it really is a perk that comes automatic with using the Token-2022 Program, is there a danger of someone explicitly creating an ATA *without* immutable ownership?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since all associated token accounts (ATAs) are [PDAs](https://solanacookbook.com/core-concepts/pdas.html) of the associated token account program (ATA program), only the ATA program can make ATAs and therefore all ATAs will have immutable ownership.

So to answer your question: **No, there is no danger of creating an ATA without immutable ownership.**

Comment: So immutable ownership is applied by default for all Token-2022 tokens and there is no way to NOT have it be applied when creating ATAs. This is a good thing. Many thanks. The docs make it seem like it is an optional extension! :D